# Performing database write with Kotlin Coroutines and Realm causes UI freeze

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use Kotlin Coroutines to write data asynchronously to Realm database, with following code:

```kotlin
suspend fun write(realmObject): Unit = with(realmDatabase) {
    beginTransaction()
    insertOrUpdate(realmObject)
    commitTransaction()
}
```

I'm calling the write method in my repository:

```kotlin
suspend fun insertALotOfObjects() {
    for (i in 0..1000) {
        val realmObjectToInsert = SampleRealmObject(id = i)
        realmRepository.write(realmObjectToInsert)
    }
}
```

And i'm using my repository inside ViewModel this way:

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    repository.insertALotOfObjects()
}
```

Each time I run my ViewModel, and click the button that starts database coroutine, UI freezes completely, to the point where even the button state is not updated, and it's stuck displaying the after-click ripple effect, until database operations are finished. When coroutine is finished, UI returns to normal state and becomes responsive again.

I've logged `Thread.currentThread()` output inside all of these calls, and current thread value is always `Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main]`, so coroutine is in fact running in worker thread.

Why does it happen? Shouldn't UI be blocked only when `UiThread` or `MainThread` are used to call the coroutine? How can I solve this problem and make UI responsive, while coroutine is running?

Comment: No clue about the UI freeze based on this code, everything should be running on the IO dispatcher, as you've said. One note though: if all the calls inside your suspending methods are blocking, you don't need the `suspend` modifier on them, it won't have any practical effect for you. You can make those calls all regular blocking functions, and then call them inside your coroutine, where you're on a background thread that will be blocked while your operation is running - which is fine.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I desperately tried to eliminate all possibilities of UI freeze, so I switched them all to `suspend` looking for a cause.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using `runBlocking {` somewhere? Though I do wonder where `realmDatabase` variable comes from.

Comment: No, I'm not running anything else than this. `realmDatabase` is just `val realmDatabase = Realm.getInstance()`, I've skipped it to post less code.

Comment: Looks alright to me,  are you sure `Dispatcher.Main` or `runBlocking{}` is not involved anywhere?

Comment: I'm 100% sure, I've checked multiple times, including logging running threads and stack

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

You were creating a new Transaction every time in a loop.  Instead, create **one** transaction, and do your `write` operation inside of it as many times as you want.